# How do you add a line segment to a stripchart in R?

Tags: r, stripchart

This is likely a very easy question, but I'm not great with R and haven't found a simple answer elsewhere on the internet.

I want to add a line segment connecting the two points in this stripchart, but cannot figure out how to do so.

```
stripchart(c(0.5, 1.5), pch = "+")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data frame or vectors with the coordinates for the line and plot with `lines`

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0.5, 1.5),
                  y = 1)

stripchart(c(0.5, 1.5), pch = "+")
lines(df1$x, df1$y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>